# Elsevier Latex Template

Tags: templates, elsarticle

Manuscript Preparation: Please, i have  a question about " The text should be in single-column format " so i can't use this:

```
 \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
```

in my latex code ?

I'd like to submit a journal paper to JPDC Journal.

Thank you so much for answer.

Kind regards.

Comment: Single-column and `twocolumn` kind of are oposites. Leave `twocolumn` out.

Comment: @Johannes_B The `5p` option needs to be removed as well, possibly replaced with `3p`. (I don't have that much experience with Elsevier, so not sure.)

Comment: In the template, i have 5 choices : %% \documentclass[final,1p,times]{elsarticle}
 %\documentclass[final,1p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,3p,times]{elsarticle}
 %\documentclass[final,3p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
%% \documentclass[final,5p,times]{elsarticle}
 \documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{elsarticle}

Comment: Which I have to choose please ? Bests.

Comment: as far as I remember "?p" depends on the journal (there is a list somewhere on the elsevier sites, which journals are in which group). Also, if i remember correctly, they want submissions using one-column even if the published journal is two-column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For detailed information about the properties and options of the `elsarticle` document class, I recommend you bring up a command window and type

```
texdoc elsarticle
```

and start reading the user guide for this document class.

For sure, I would *not* specify the options `final`, `5p`, and `twocolumn`.  Instead, I would try

```
\documentclass[times]{elsarticle}
```

The default options, i.e., those that needn't be specified explicitly in order to be in effect, are `a4paper`, `10pt`, `oneside`, `onecolumn` and `preprint`. For a journal submission, it may also be unnecessary to specify `times` (an option for the text font to be used in the document).

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have to use this for example: \documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}   ?

Comment: @researcher -- Assuming JPDC stands for Journal of Parallel and Distributed Computing, this option combination should be OK. Incidentally, why would you wish to set the option `12pt`? Does the journal require it?

Answer (score 0):

The Xp refers to the page sizes used by the journal. 1p is single column, 3p is single column by default and 5p is double column. For double column formatting, use 1p or 3p.

The final options shows a style similar to (but different from) the style used on [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/). For submitting your article, you may want to use the option *review* rather than *final*.